# Dynamically store data.frames using c("df1", "df2, "df3") etc

Tags: r

I have the following code:

I download balance sheet information and I use `rbind` to store the information in a data.frame

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
setwd('C:/Users/Matt/Desktop/Stefano')

library(quantmod)
symbols <- c("HOG", "GE", "GOOG")
symbols.f <- sapply(symbols, function(x) { paste0(x, ".f") })
symbols <- sub("\\.f","", symbols.f)

financials <- list()
for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {   
 financials[i] <- list(getFinancials(symbols[i], src="yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE))
}
```

My issue is with the following;

```
for(j in 1:length(symbols)) {
df[[j]] <- rbind(financials[[j]]$IS$A, financials[[j]]$BS$A, financials[[j]]$CF$A)
}
```

The code works when I use

`dftest <- rbind(financials[[1]]$IS$A, financials[[1]]$BS$A, financials[[1]]$CF$A)`

However I would like to name the data.frames according to the `symbols` values.

That is;

```
HOG <- rbind(financials[[1]]$IS$A, financials[[1]]$BS$A, financials[[1]]$CF$A)
GE <- rbind(financials[[2]]$IS$A, financials[[2]]$BS$A, financials[[2]]$CF$A)
GOOG <- rbind(financials[[3]]$IS$A, financials[[3]]$BS$A, financials[[3]]$CF$A)
```

Comment: Your example clearly shows that you know how to use lists. Change what you "would like" to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning global variables programmatically is generally not a good idea. However, it can be achieved in R via `assign`:

```
symbols <- c("HOG", "GE", "GOOG")
for (i in seq_along(symbols)) {
  assign(symbols[i], rbind(financials[[i]]$IS$A, financials[[i]]$BS$A, financials[[i]]$CF$A))
}
```

The preferred way, suggested in the comments, is to use a `list`:

```
result <- list()
for (i in seq_along(symbols)) {
  result[[symobls[i]]] <- rbind(...)
}
```